# Not able to read id with dot and dash characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div with id **"Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.ViewProperties-Large"**.
I am not able to hide it using javascript. I am using `\\` to escape dot but its not working.Below is my code.

```
document.getElementById("Ribbon\\.ListItem\\.Manage\\.ViewProperties-Large  ").style.display = "none";
```

Its giving below error.

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Comment: Oh goodness. Consider changing the IDs if possible..

Answer (score 1):

When you use getElementById there is no need to escape the `.` since we are not using a selector

```
document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.ViewProperties-Large").style.display = "none";
```

But if you are using jQuery then you will have to escape the selector related characters like `.$#` etc

```
$('#Ribbon\\.ListItem\\.Manage\\.ViewProperties-Large').hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to escape anything when passing an id to `document.getElementById`. It knows it’s an id, not a selector.

```
document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.ViewProperties-Large  ").style.display = "none";
```

You might also want to remove the trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use escape characters when using `getElementById`.Use as

```
document.getElementById('Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.ViewProperties-Large').style.display = "none";
```

You can see a simple implementation in at http://jsbin.com/tuwaruhusu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Below code is working for me...not working with javascript only...any cluse why?

Comment: <style type="text/css">
#Ribbon\.ListItem\.Manage\.ViewProperties-Large  
{     
 display:none !important; 
}
</style>

Comment: Its working now...I was putting it under document.ready ....i removed it from there .. it started working thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Hope it helps.

```
<style> #Ribbon\.ListItem\.Manage\.ViewProperties-Large{display:none;} </style>
```